# Very slow RMI+SSL requests after added SSL certificate

Tags: centos, iptables, java

I added a SSL certificate to a RMI based application, and it's working normally on test server, so after deploy it at production servers, all requests are waiting for SSL handshake, even local connections, it's caused by some iptables rules that production servers have.

Basically, all is blocked, and just only allowing needed ports. Below our default iptables rules executed by `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#Flush all
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

#Chains
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

#Allow local connections
iptables -A INPUT -s localhost -d localhost -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -d $ip -j ACCEPT

#RMI ports (for rmi app)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1826 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1827 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 18026 -j ACCEPT

#allowing RMI socket port range
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 20000:65535 -j ACCEPT

#Allow apache, https, tomcat ports
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

#Allow pings
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

#Allow DNS
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 953 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 953 -j ACCEPT
```

I don't have much knowledge about iptables rules, but I think that at moment of SSL handshake, some request can be sent to Digicert or it uses some port or protocol that isn't allowed (for instance), and some missing iptables rule is causing this 'eternal waiting'.

Did anyone already had same or similar problem like this?

**Info**

Servers: CentOS 6.5 x64 at digitalocean.
App: JVM 1.8, RMI based for thin desktop clients and Tomcat (8080) for web users. Tomcat connections uses local rmi connections.

**Update**

Works adding these rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s secure.globalsign.com -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s ocsp.globalsign.com -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s ocsp2.globalsign.com -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s crl.globalsign.com -j ACCEPT
```

However, the handshake still a little bit slow.

Comment: Add the text form of your certificate to your question, obtained by `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cerificate file>`.

Comment: Sorry, is it .JKS file, .CERT/CRT file? I have here, ssl.jks (added to Tomcat connector), p7b file used to assign ssl.jks file. I'm a little bit noob about SSL :/

Comment: I think you'll therefore need `keytool -printcert -v <certificate file>`. My thoughts is that your server is checking revocation of certificates in the chain (either CRL or OCSP) but failing to reach the relevant server.  Printing the content of the certificate will show what URLs need checking.

Comment: gareth, I got this with your keytool command: https://gist.github.com/carlosjrcabello/267da99933d380d0a7911cac0665368a I'm testing adding globalsign urls in my iptables rules

Comment: Try to access the two CRLDistributionPoint URLs from the server with, for example, `wget`.

Comment: resolving is a little bit slow, https://gist.github.com/carlosjrcabello/0dd9c42fd8cb214641fd091955e69284 Now I don't know if my server dns is slow, but I can fetch url content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40719/discussion-between-carlos-a-junior-and-gareththered).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm switching off now, however the delay may be down to the time your servers are taking to retrieve the OCSP response. `wget http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2` and `wget http://ocsp.globalsign.com/rootr1` are instantaneous on my system. It may be worth investigating this first.  Good luck :-)

Comment: So, I realize some droplets are getting response instantaneous some others not, the unique difference is some are their physical locations, NY and SF (DigitalOcean). But, could be my code wrong ? Can you look this snippet ? https://gist.github.com/carlosjrcabello/449747f7330596e27cdd2ad20a6fd5ba

Comment: I've found this thread talking about this problem, http://www.coderanch.com/t/656284/sockets/java/HttpsServer-SSL-extremely-slow-times . I'll review my code to looking up problems.